# Remove "pub" from media URL in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1

How can we remove "pub" from the media URL? Like below:
`www.xyz.com/media/catalog/product` from `www.xyz.com/pub/media/catalog/product` . we have googled but not found any solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**`Magento version 2.3.1`**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your Root Directory.
Follow DevDoc for more detail https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: Thanks, @Divyarajsinh you saved my day.